# MySQL query count with subsort by type

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if anyone can help with this

I have the following tables

```
user_ids {
    uUID
    name
}

types {
    tUID
    name
}

activity {
    aUID
    user_id
    type_id
    date
}
```

so users would contain

```
uUID    name
1       Bob
2       Mark
3       Peter
```

types would be

```
tUID    name
1       Baseball
2       Football
3       Cricket
```

activity would be

```
aUID    user_id    type_id    date
1         1           2
2         1           2
3         1           3
4         2           1
5         2           3
6         2           1
7         3           3
8         3           3
9         3           3
```

now what I would like to get is the following table back

```
Name   Type      Count of type
Bob    Baseball  0
Bob    Football  2
Bob    Cricket   1
Mark   Baseball  2
Mark   Football  0
Mark   Cricket   1
Peter  Baseball  0
Peter  Football  0
Peter  Cricket   3
```

I can do this with single query's per user id but would like to know if there is a way to do this with a single query instead.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**With zero**

```
SELECT X.Name ,X.Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as `Count of type`
FROM
(
    SELECT T.Name AS Type,U.name AS NAME,U.uUID,T.tuid FROM types T,user_ids U
)X  LEFT JOIN activity A ON A.type_id = X.tuid AND A.user_id =X.uUID
GROUP BY X.Name ,X.Type
ORDER BY X.Name ,X.Type
```

**Without zero**

```
SELECT U.name AS Name, 
       T.name AS Type, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as `Count of type`
FROM types T
LEFT JOIN activity a on T.tuid=A.type_id
JOIN user_ids U on A.user_id = U.uUID
GROUP BY U.name, T.name
```

Comment: The With zero statement doesn't appear to return 0 if the user hasn't done any activities or has only done 1 EG

    Peter Cricket 3

but nothing else

Comment: No it will return either user has done some activity or not

Answer (score 2):

You just have to left join type and activity tables and group by user and type:

```
select u.name as Name, t.name as Type, COUNT(a.user_id) as `Count of type`
from type t
left join activity a on t.tuid=a.type_id
left join users u on a.user_id = u.uUID
group by u.name, t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is using `CROSS JOIN` of `users` and `types`, then a `LEFT JOIN` with `activity`.

```
select u.name as Name, t.name as Type, COUNT(a.aUID) as `Count of type`
from users u CROSS JOIN type t
    LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.user_id = u.uUID AND a.type_id = t.tUID
```